# How do I use Calculate() in Powerpivot as an alternative to if function

Tags: dax, powerpivot

My question is this. I have created an `IF` formula in Excel - which works fine. However, I got an error message when I tried to use this formula as a calculated column in PowerPivot. Apparently because of the number of ors in it.  So basically I need to create it as a measure. I reckon I need a `CALCULATE()` function but just want a couple of pointers on where to start. I know I have to reference the table name in it not just the column name.

```
IF(OR([Deferred %]=1,[Deferred %]=0, [In Contract Date]="NO"),
    0,
    IF([S&M  Contract Start date]=[Revenue Date],
        ([Amount]*(1-[Deferred %])+[Amount]/[Revenue Days]),
        ([Deferred %]*[Amount])/[Revenue Days]),0)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would be because in power pivot calculation language DAX the `OR` and `AND` functions only take two inputs, unlike excel which allows for multiple inputs.

A simple way around this would be the following:

```
OR(OR([Deferred %]=1,[Deferred %]=0), [In Contract Date]="NO")
```

The other option is using `||` which is for or.
This replacing your condition as,

```
[Deferred %]=1 || [Deferred %]=0 || [In Contract Date]="NO"
```